# Using a Designer .ui File in Your Application example not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to build a UI form and interface to it using the example from:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

```
#include "ui_item.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget;
    Ui::Item ui;
    ui.setupUi(&widget);

    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

However, it just doesn't work. In the line
`ui.setupUi(&widget);` I get the error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘QWidget*’ to ‘QFrame*’
```

Is there something I'm missing?  The top-level widget in `Ui::Item` is a `QFrame`.  I'm using Qt 5.12 and Qt-Creator 4.12.4.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my UI top level was a QFrame and it needed to be a QWidget.  For whatever reason, the UI file generated as a QFrame.